# Sorting a list of images by the average pixel value of each image

Tags: python, list, image, sorting

I have a list of greyscale pillow images.
I would like to sort that list in terms of the average pixel value of each image.

My most recent attempt is below:

```
def getTiles(tiles_directory):    
    files = os.listdir(tiles_directory)
    tiles = []
    for file in files:
        filePath =os.path.abspath(os.path.join(tiles_directory, file))
        try:
            fp = open(filePath, "rb")
            im = Image.open(fp)            
            im = ImageOps.grayscale(im)            
            
            tiles.append(im)
            im.load()
            fp.close()
        except:
            print("Invalid tile: %s" % (filePath,))
    return (tiles)

input_tiles = getTiles(file_repository)

images_sorted_by_ave_pixel = sorted(
    input_tiles, key=lambda x: ImageStat.Stat(x).mean)
```

But I get an error:

```
  File "StitchMosaic.py", line 351, in generate
sorted_tiles=sortTiles(tiles)
  File "StitchMosaic.py", line 50, in sortTiles
byAvePixel = sorted(tiles, key=lambda x: ImageStat.Stat(x).mean)
  File "StitchMosaic.py", line 50, in <lambda>
byAvePixel = sorted(tiles, key=lambda x: ImageStat.Stat(x).mean)
  File "/Users/stuartfish/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/ImageStat.py", line 39, in __init__
raise TypeError("first argument must be image or list")

TypeError: first argument must be image or list
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you post more of your code please? Like where you create `list_of_images`?

Comment: Use `type` method to know what you are passing as an argument.

Comment: Also please paste the full error stacktrace.

Comment: `return (tiles)` --> `return tiles`

Comment: Thanks all so far. #Vishal Kumar Sahu, I will use the type method as suggested . #balderman I tried removing the brackets in my return statement but it made no difference.  It probably is a really basic error as this is my first attempt at python.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. The answer was a simple error on my part - highlighted by #Vishal Kumar Sahu - the existence of the type() method will make my debugging much easier :)

Despite my lengthy variables names I still managed to pass a string instead of a list of image objects.